# Java multiple interfaces implementation

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

the setting is like this. 
I have multiple interfaces (i.e. A,B,C) and I have classes (Z and Y) to implements them 
**X implements A,B{}** and **Y implements A,C{}** and **Z implements B,C{}**

Some functions in interface A,B,C have the same definition and I don't want to retype them in each class, how should I do?

I did google it, and notice that one solution is to use a handy keyword **default** in the interface. But what if I am prohibited from using this keyword, like the code is compatible with version prior than Java8? 

Is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: Can you describe the problem more clearly? If `A`, `B` and `C` all share a method named `f` with the same signature, and `W` implements all three interfaces, you still just need to write the implementation once.

Comment: You should consider using java 8 or even 11 since older versions are not supported by Oracle and most people have migrated to java 8 or 11.

Comment: let A has functions: a1,a2,a3
B has b1,b2,b3
C has c1,c2,c3

a1, b1 and c1 have the same definition, otherwise different definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should go with abstract class and provide some default implementation for the common methods in different interfaces as below.

```
interface A {
    void m1();
    void common();
}

interface B {
    void m2();
    void common();
}

abstract class ABClass implements A, B {

    public void common() {
    System.out.println("Default");
}

Class X extends ABClass {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of gaining these methods through inheritance and having to extend mutliple classes to get your definitions in, you could [favor composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and take a class that implements the method you want to reuse as a parameter. Keeping it as a private final member variable, you can call this common method in a generic way.

Comment: won't this make the code less comprehensible? I am still learning OOP, can you provide me a simple example? thank.